# JavaScript: Variable always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following script to store the value of the variable "muted_status" and then pass it into a cookie but it seems like the variable always has a false value.

```
var muted_status = false;
$('#jp_container_1').on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#jp_container_1').hasClass("jp-state-muted")) {
        var muted_status = true;
        } else {
        var muted_status = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
$.cookie('jp_mute', muted_status, { expires: 7, path: '/'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you're re-declaring a `muted_status` variable multiple times, which means that the variable you set in your `setTimeout` function is not the same as the one used by the call to `$.cookie`. Second, and most importantly, the call to `$.cookie` is happening synchronously, immediately after you set the timeout, whereas the `muted_status` is being set one second later.

Perhaps something like this is what you're going for?

```
function setMutedStatus(mutedStatus) {
    $.cookie('jp_mute', mutedStatus, { expires: 7, path: '/'});
}
setMutedStatus(false);
$('#jp_container_1').on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var mutedStatus = $('#jp_container_1').hasClass("jp-state-muted");
        setMutedStatus(mutedStatus);
    }, 1000);
});
```

This begins by setting the cookie to muted, but it may then set it to something else one second later. If your intent is to check the muted status every second, you'll want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.